Brakes are bad, possibly after replacing the ABS
I have a 2017 Ford Fusion Sport with ~80k km (50k miles).
I purchased it after an accident. The car was hit to the front, but the only damaged thing (outside of the bumper) was the radiator. That is to say, it got nowhere near the brakes at all.
What I also wanted to do is install some additional mods, which forced me to remove the ABS module. It was out of the vehicle for more than a week. But the important thing here is I have photo proof that the brake reservoir did not go dry. It had almost the same amount of liquid as it did when I started - because I didn't the remove the reservoir cap.
After the vehicle was fully repaired, and ABS back into place, I've added quite a bit of liquid and forced as much air as I could by pumping the brake pedal.
Still, the brake pedal feel was awful. About 20% of the pedal travel would barely stop the vehicle at all, and going further than 20% still wouldn't feel "catchy". I've had a 2014 Fusion before that, and have test driven friend's 2017 Fusion - both had quite a different pedal feel, and both had the same brake booster and even smaller rotors/pads. On low speeds, pressing the pedal about 20% would instantly stop the vehicle. Mine doesn't do that even with >40% pressed pedal.
What I did afterwards:

got a shop to bleed the brakes with a pressure bleeder
got the rotors machined
got new front brake pads, and not any cheap ones - zimmermann
got new rear brake pads, again zimmermann
got the dealership to replace front brake hoses (recall)
got the dealership to diagnose the brakes
replaced the whole ABS unit
got another shop to bleed the brakes with a pressure bleeder
tried pressure bleeding myself, making sure to run the ABS bleed procedure with a scanner beforehand - almost zero air bubbles
tried bleeding the master cylinder myself - by connecting the caliper bleed valves to the reservior, and pumping the brake about 100 times to cycle the fluid - zero air bubbles
checked the vacuum at the brake booster - 90-100kPa, while Ford specifies normal range of 51-74kPa
checked the brake booster for leaks - 5 hours after stopping the engine, there was still about 90kPa of vacuum, and the pedal feel was the same as with the engine running
of course, there are no DTCs

All of this yielded absolutely no results. The pedal feel is awful, and the car is hard to stop. The dealership sees no problem with my brakes and other shops just recommend replacing random things like the booster or the master cylinder.
I'm lost here, as I seem to have tried everything. Any ideas on how to diagnose this, please?

Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair!

If you pull the ABS fuse and if you can find a safe place to try it on clean, hard, dry pavement, can you drive at something like 40 km/h (25 mph) and slam on the brakes hard enough to screech the tires or leave skid marks? Not to be a d*ck about it, but I'm really looking for a yes or no answer without nuance. And then if you restore the fuse and pull the same maneuver, does the ABS modulate the brakes in the well-known, expected manner to prevent wheel lock-up and stop in just a slightly longer distance?
